# Is it possible to pass ressources per thread when using JAVA parallel streams?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-stream

My question is really simple, but I didn't found a topic answering it clearly... (maybe I missed it... :o). 
I would like to know, when using parallel streams, if it is possible to give to each thread custom data (different for each thread).

For example, we could imagine that I want to know which thread treated which entity.

Ex : I have the following collection [0,1,2,3,4,5]
I create parallel streams and use the map method to have the square associated to each element.
I should have the following output : [0,1,4,9,16,25]
But I would like to identify which thread handled which entities, so for example, if I have 2 threads :

thread 1 -> [0,1,2]

thread 2 -> [3,4,5]

I hope I'm clear, thanks by advance to the ones who'll take the time to answer my question !

Comment: Why would want this kind of information ?

Comment: Re, "...which thread treated which entity..." You are assuming that only one thread "treats" each "entity." That assumption might not be valid for a non-trivial stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Thread.currentThread()` you can get the thread from the currently active context.

See this small snippet:

```
final int[] ints = IntStream.range(0, 6)
    .parallel()
    .map(i -> {
        System.out.println("thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " maps " + i + " to " + i * i);
        return i * i;
    })
    .toArray();

System.out.println("Final array " + Arrays.toString(ints));
```

Prints something like this:

```
thread main maps 5 to 25
thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1 maps 2 to 4
thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2 maps 3 to 9
thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3 maps 0 to 0
thread main maps 1 to 1
thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4 maps 4 to 16
Final array [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Though this is not deterministic, e.g. every iteration will probably result in a different print outcome

Comment: If you use the result of `Thread.currentThread()` as the unique index of an object in a container, then you are pretty much re-inventing `java.lang.ThreadLocal`.